When was the word "octave" first used?
I was rereading Etymology of word "Octave" just now, and I noticed many people, myself included, speculating on the impact of the medieval state of the mathematics, the timing of the introduction of zero, and that sort of thing:

Just a guess, but doesn’t “octava” predate the introduction of zero as a concept? –
Jim Garrison Oct 24, 2018 at 16:25
... In the 11th century, Guido d'Arezzo was using inclusive counting, for example the Greek diatesseron for the perfect fourth, where four is téssera in Greek (τέσσερα). The concept probably existed earlier than the 11C, of course. –
phoog Oct 24, 2018 at 20:42

But then I remembered that Guido used the Greek name diapason for the interval that we call "octave" today, and the etymology of that word does not relate to the number eight.  (It relates to the concept of spanning all of the notes without saying how many there are.)
So who first used the word "octave" in the modern music-theoretical sense, and, more importantly, when?

By "the word 'octave'" I mean any word in any language that relates to the number eight, though I expect that it will most likely be the Latin word octava or some variant thereof.  Fux used octava in his 1725 Gradus ad Parnassum, so it can't be any later than that, but I suspect that it was already in use much earlier.
I'm primarily interested in European music theory and counting conventions, but if you know of early numeric names for this interval in any other field of music theory, for example in China or India, that would certainly be interesting, too.


Seems likely that non-musical uses of the word would precede musical; see https://www.etymonline.com/word/octave#etymonline_v_2482

Also note from that Etymonline page, "musical sense of "note eight diatonic degrees above (or below) a given note" is by 1650s, from Latin octava (pars) "eighth part." Formerly English eighth was used in this sense (mid-15c.)." Might be nice to know what that 1650s source is...

I guess actually "formerly English eighth was used," although the entry isn't focused on the musical sense at that point, allows the possibility that we should be looking beyond the first use of "octave" to see if there are any early uses just talking about the "interval of an eighth."

TL;DR
Octave, as octava, and meaning "an interval of eight notes", goes back to 13th-century Italian (see OED, below). It possibly goes back earlier in Middle High German, which is dated from 1050 – 1350 (Wikipedia)

The first known usage of "octave" in English, according to the Oxford English Dictionary:

The earliest known use of the word octave is in the late 1500s.


OED's earliest evidence for octave is from around 1570, in Art of Music [author not given].

Regarding etymology:

octave is a borrowing from Latin.


Etymons: Latin octava, octāva, octāvus.


As noun < post-classical Latin octava an octave in music (a1487 in a British source; compare note below), use as noun of classical Latin octāva, feminine singular of octāvus eighth < octo eight (see octo- comb. form); compare ancient Greek ὄγδοος eighth (see ogdoad n.). As adjective < classical Latin octāvus eighth, in post-classical Latin also in musical sense (e.g. 1533 in the passage translated in quot. 1651 at sense B). In sense A.2a after Italian ottava (a1597 in this sense); compare Spanish octava (1590 in this sense in the passage translated in quot. 1604 at sense A.2a). In sense A.3 after Portuguese †oitava. Compare Middle French, French octave interval of eight notes (1534), type of organ stop (1535), stanza of eight verses (1694), position in fencing (1771), Italian ottava interval of eight notes (14th cent.; 13th cent as octava), Middle High German octāv (German Oktave) the eighth note on a scale, interval of eight notes. Compare earlier octave n.1


Note, phoog is looking for languages other than English as well (e.g., did Italian ottavo predate?). And sounds like is also counting English use of the word "eighth" to refer to an octave. And we get into "what counts as English?"; it seems clear that utave and similar spellings are present from 12th century in Middle English, Norman, early Spanish, or whatever the heck we're looking at in here and here.

I wonder whether the "around 1570 Art of Music" is in fact this 1565 Arte de Tañer Fantasia, in which I found on p. 10 of part 1, "Lo mesmo sea de entender desus octauas." Oh look, it's also on p 9, "... todas las octauas tiene el nombre de un mismo signo, y unas mismas bozes, y unas mismas propriedades, y porque Gamaut es octaua de Gesolreut, por tanto tambien le llamamos, & intitulamos Gesolreut..." A lot of that escapes me, but "the gamut is octave" stands out. The Gesolreut stuff is...

... identifying which octave is in question, e.g. "G sol re ut." I think that whole paragraph is explaining to the novice that the properties of an octave are applicable to all the other octaves.

@AndyBonner the full OED entry indicates that The Art of Music is in fact this anonymous Scottish manuscript: https://www.diamm.ac.uk/sources/1870/#/ to be found in the British Library (I have OED access but not BL access...)

Maybe I am misinterpreting the question, but Pythagoras identified the frequency ratio 2:1 and named it the octave.
The ancient Greeks also defined scales that used the octave.
From Wikipedia:
"After the discovery of the fundamental intervals (octave, fourth and fifth), the first known systematic divisions of the octave were those of Pythagoras to whom was often attributed the discovery that the frequency of a vibrating string is inversely proportional to its length. Pythagoras construed the intervals arithmetically, allowing for 1:1 = Unison, 2:1 = Octave, 3:2 = Fifth, 4:3 = Fourth. Pythagoras's scale consists of a stack of perfect fifths, the ratio 3:2 (see also Pythagorean Interval and Pythagorean Tuning).
The earliest such description of a scale is found in Philolaus fr. B6. Philolaus recognizes that, if the interval of a fourth goes up from any given note, and then up the interval of a fifth, the final note is an octave above the first note. Thus, the octave is made up of a fourth and a fifth. ... Philolaus's scale thus consisted of the following intervals: 9:8, 9:8, 256:243 [these three intervals take us up a fourth], 9:8, 9:8, 9:8, 256:243 [these four intervals make up a fifth and complete the octave from our starting note]. This scale is known as the Pythagorean diatonic and is the scale that Plato adopted in the construction of the world soul in the Timaeus (36a-b).[12]"

Pythagoras for sure didn't use the word "octava", as he'd be speaking Greek, not Latin, and it doesn't seem likely he used any other word related to the number eight, either. If you think he did, support it with some evidence. Otherwise I'm going to think he used the same word that was in use by the 11th century: "διαπασῶν", which apparently means "through all".
